# How to pipe parameter string to excutable in python?

Tags: python

Say I need to do the following in python:

```
import os
os.system("a.out 1 \n 3 \n 2 \n 5 \n 2...")
```

Here I have separate string to store the parameters:

```
par="1 \n 3 \n 2 \n 5 \n 2..."
```

Not sure how to pipe it to "a.out" in python. Thanks!

Comment: Might want to check out the subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE

Comment: Do you want to pass the `1 \n 3 \n2...` on the command line or on its standard input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to pass that string to stdin,

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['a.out'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate('1 \n 3 \n 2 \n 5 \n 2...\n')
```

Edit: since you want to read from a file, that's actually even easier.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['a.out'], stdin=file('a.inp'))
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to pipe a input file to the excitable: a.out <a.inp

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
os.system('a.out %s' % par)
```